# как взять ссылку на товар? хотел пропарсить сайт с товарами все сделал а ссылку не знаю как взять

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

```
`import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = ("https://krisha.kz/arenda/kvartiry/almaty/")

   

responce = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(responce, 'lxml')
check = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'a-card__inc')
for result in check:
    print(result.text.strip())`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код уже почти готов, вам просто нужно найти правильный HTML-тег и класс, который содержит ссылку на товар. Обычно это тег `<a>` с атрибутом `href`. Вот как вы можете это сделать:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://krisha.kz/arenda/kvartiry/almaty/"

response = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')
check = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'a-card__inc')

for result in check:
    link = result.find('a', href=True)  # Находим тег <a> с атрибутом href
    if link:
        print(link['href'])  # Печатаем значение атрибута href
```

Comment: а еще можно спросить как мне ссылку сделать чтобы она сайт открывала?

Comment: ссылка выгладит вот так /a/show/689495319

Comment: а все я понял как сделать